# Jquery popup windows automaticly pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I've gotten an piece of Jquery code which lets the user click a link which will open an popup with information. But I don't know how to modify it so that the popup automaticly opens up when the user loads the page.

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('[data-popup-target]').click(function () {
        $('html').addClass('overlay');
        var activePopup = $(this).attr('data-popup-target');
        $(activePopup).addClass('visible');

    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 && $('html').hasClass('overlay')) {
            clearPopup();
        }
    });

    $('.popup-exit').click(function () {
        clearPopup();

    });

    $('.popup-overlay').click(function () {
        clearPopup();
    });

    function clearPopup() {
        $('.popup.visible').addClass('transitioning').removeClass('visible');
        $('html').removeClass('overlay');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popup').removeClass('transitioning');
        }, 200);
    }

});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Link to activate the code:

```
    <a href="#example-popup" data-popup-target="#example-popup">Link</a>
```

Content of popup window:

```
<div id="example-popup" class="popup">
    <div class="popup-body">    <span class="popup-exit"></span>

        <div class="popup-content">
                <h2 class="popup-title">Terms and Conditions</h2>
                <p>
                <h5><font color="grey">Please take time to read the following...</font></h5>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="popup-overlay"></div>
```

I've tried modifying it mysql, but it didn't work out. As I'm not an expert in Jquery.
I know it is a big ask, but the code is here. And I know some geek can easily find what I need :)

So real quick. Instead of having the user to click the link to open the popup. I want the popup to automaticly open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonably simple when you trigger a click on the element you want after you register the click handler.

```
/* your original code stays mostly the same except for chaining methods after it*/
$('[data-popup-target]').click(function () {
    $('html').addClass('overlay');
    var activePopup = $(this).attr('data-popup-target');
    $(activePopup).addClass('visible');
 /* now click the first one */
}).first().click();
```

ID's must be unique in a page, so you should change the duplicates on the popup link and popup container if they are the same as shown